# Travelling to Romania through Turkey with a Pakistani ordinary passport

Tags: visas, turkey, romania, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am travelling to Romania with Turkish airlines with a 10 hour layover in Istanbul. I have a valid Romanian visa, am I eligible to get a Turkish e-visa? The conditions on the e-visa website are confusing. Romania is part of the EU but not a full-fledged Schengen state.

Answer (score 2):

If you go through the application for the [Turkish E Visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/apply/) you will get to the prerequisites page.

So if you hold a Schengen visa or an [OECD country](http://www.oecd.org/about/membersandpartners/list-oecd-member-countries.htm) visa you are eligible to have one.

Romania as of this time is not a party to either one of these agreements so to get a eVisa you will need to have a visa for another country that is a party to one of these agreements.  Save that obtain a regular visa or stay at the airport for which you're not required to have a visa.